# onclick javascript anywhere in site, open another site in new tab

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tabs, onclick

I have a wordpress site, and have some good traffic, I want that, if a visitor come first time and click any where on the site, a new tab will open with my an other site.
Is this possible? if yes then what will be the code? i need code in javascript.
regards

Comment: Try to search more deeply on Google.. you'll find the answer and the code as well.. Please do not expect us to do your job. :)

Comment: it will occur only once or always?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
   var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
   win.focus();
});
```

Comment: can you please give me the complete code, and i want that only once new tab open, after that no more tab, either visitor will stay on the site until visitor wants, i just want that only once new tab will open.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `<body>` tag with this one:

```
<body onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')">
```

Comment: I use this one, but i want, that tab open only once, after that no more tab will open with my 2nd website.

Comment: Use js cookies to check if user has been already there!

Comment: how can i do this? can you please help me? i am not good with this.

Comment: im not very experienced in js, but I suggest you to use php. If you can use it, let me know and i will help you!

Comment: Yes please tell me, how can i use this with php? i have site in wordpress, where i want this.

Comment: `<body onclick="<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])){echo"window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')"; setcookie("visited", "1", time()+3600*24*365);} ?>">` This is it

Comment: thanks buddy, this one is working perfectly for me.

Comment: can i set time for every 24 hours? like that user will come again for 25 hours then?

Comment: i have applied this script, but i am getting problem, until i click on other page, if i click anywhere on the page, 1 time 2 time or 3 time, everytime the new tab open, if i click on the menu or next page, then windows will not open, i just want that only once, just once window page open.

Comment: `<body onclick="<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])){echo"window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')"; setcookie("visited", "1", time()+3600*24*365); header("Refresh:0");} ?>">` This is for 1 year

Comment: `<body onclick="<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])){echo"window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')"; setcookie("visited", "1", time()+3600*24); header("Refresh:0");} ?>">` This is for every day

Answer (score 1):

Over a link , we can give the address and the target so that the required URL opens in a new window.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```